# Angular JS error states not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 page with 3 panels and a numeric stepper to control the height of the panels.  This part works fine, but I also am trying to add and error state message if the stepper goes to the minimum or over a value. The stepper value is bound to the panels' height and works as expected.  The error does not display, though.

The basic angular part of the code is here:

```
<form class="form-inline" name="panel" no-validate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': panel.height.$error.min || panel.height.$error.max}" >
            <span>Change height:&nbsp;</span>
            <input class="form-control" name="height" style="display: inline-block; width: 70px;" type="number" min="150" max="400" step="25" ng-model="panelHeight" ng-init="panelHeight=200"  />
            <span ng-show="panel.height.$error.min">&nbsp;Height must be a minimum of 150.</span>
            <span ng-show="panel.height.$error.max">&nbsp;Height must be a maximum of 400.</span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And a fiddle with the whole working code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yLUaA/

**NOTE** Apparently I am having issues removing just the right amount of code to make the fiddle work; rest assured the panel sizing is working locally.  Just not the error.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't appear to be working? What should happen when you input a number?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have `ng-app` anywhere

Comment: Argh.  Not sure why it's no working, it works on my html page.  Perhaps I left something off.  As you click the up-down stepper the 3 panels below should match their height to that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `ng-app` from the fiddle so that's most likely the cause in your local project. `ng-app` should be assigned to the root element of your page, see [ng-app documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yLUaA/3/

Comment: No, I have it in my app.  It's an invalided app, I am trying to excise the smallest possible part. And the fiddle you linked to doesn't work either.

Comment: Then the problem isn't with the code you supplied because as you can see from the fiddle above, it's working.

Comment: Beats me, I've looked at the fiddle you posted in Safari 8 and Chrome 37 and the panels don't resize AND the error state doesn't work.

Comment: Panels don't resize but the error messages are working.

Comment: Ah, yes thanks my bad.  For some reason I thought I could get the error  to display when using the stepper, but I suppose it only works if an value is typed.  Which makes more sense when I think about it.  So it worked all along!  Thanks again.